# How to prevent OpenLayers from interfering with jQuery events?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, openlayers

I'm using jQueryUI to create pop up dialogs when a user clicks on a feature in my OpenLayers map. I use the following code to track the xy location of the user's mouse, which will then pop up the dialog at the mouse position on click:

```
// Track mouse position for attribute editor dialog
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
});
```

Whenever my cursor is over the OpenLayers map, the x and y values of `currentMousePos` do not change. As soon as my mouse hovers over any other element, the x and y values update accordingly. Also, when resizing the dialog over the map, the resizing is laggy when expanding since the mouse is dragging over the web map. As soon as the cursor is not hovering over the map, resizing the dialog works smoothly. **Does anyone know how to prevent this interference by the OpenLayers map?** This issue was introduced in the newest version of OpenLayers (2.13) because it works fine in 2.12.

Comment: If you need to track your mouse for the "map" purposes, I suggest you don't use jQuery, but the openLayers [functionality](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/MousePosition-js.html)
then you'll only have the interference within one system and that should be no problem then...

Comment: @Mochi, Nevermind, on second look I see what you mean. `OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition` has a `lastXy` property. Thanks. Unfortunately, that was just one of the jQuery events that was interfering, so I'd still like to see if anyone knows of a fix.